# Rendering Post formats from the_content() in WordPress - there must be a better way?

Tags: php, wordpress, video

I would like to provide support for post formats in my first public theme (I usually do custom builds for clients) and would like to know, hopefully definitively, how to get the various different bits of content out, particularly for the index, and not with regards to the template hierarchy but rather extracting the specific data(ie: a video or audio URL, a gallery, a quote and author etc) from the_content().

Whats the common or standard way of doing it  - I assume filtering the content to work with these ?  any links  / tutorials, suggestion etc are welcome.

To Summarize I'm after two things

a) Should I be supporting post formats at all
b) is there a standard way of doing it?

What I'm using right now for video (for example) is (with a custom metabox):

```
  <?php
// Display Videos

// Utility function - allow us to strpos an array
if ( ! function_exists( 'video_strpos_arr' )) {
    function video_strpos_arr($haystack, $needle) {

    if( !is_array($needle) ) $needle = array($needle);

        foreach( $needle as $what ) {
            if( ($pos = strpos($haystack, $what) ) !==false ) return $pos;
        }

        return false;
    }
}

// Get Ready Display the Video
$embedCheck     = array("<embed", "<video", "<ifram");// only checking against the first 6
$mykey_values   = get_post_custom_values('_format_video_embed');
$media_to_display = '';

// check if the audio metabox is used
if ( isset($mykey_values) && !empty($mykey_values) ) {
    // iterate over values passed
    foreach ( $mykey_values as $key => $value ) {
         if ( !empty($value) ) {
            $firstCar = substr($value, 0, 6); // get the first 6 char.

            // if its a http(s).
            if ( strpos($firstCar, "http:/" ) !== false || strpos($firstCar, "https:" ) !== false ) {
                // send it to wp_oembed to see if the link is oembed enabled.
                (wp_oembed_get($value) !==false ?
                    $media_to_display = '<div class="video" style="width:100%; overflow:hidden;">' .
                    wp_oembed_get($value) . '</div>' :
                    // if not output a link.
                    $media_to_display =  '<a class="button videolink" href="' .
                    $value . '" target="_blank">Video link: ' . the_title() . '</a>'
                );
            }

            // if its the embed code that matches our array defined above.
            else if ( video_strpos_arr($firstCar, $embedCheck ) !== false ) {
                $media_to_display = '<div class="video" style="width:100%; overflow:hidden;">' .$value. '</div>';

            }
        }
    }; // end foreach
} // end conditional

if ( is_singular() ) {
    // output a filtered excerpt displaying the result of the conditionals above.
    echo apply_filters('the_content', $media_to_display );
    the_content();
} else {
    // output a filtered excerpt displaying the result of the conditionals above.
    get_template_part( 'loop/loop', 'indextitle' );
    echo apply_filters('the_excerpt', $media_to_display );
    ?><p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="button">Read More</a> <?php
}
```

Which works with the meta box, and I could use a function like this to grab the URL and pass it instead of the metabox value and then filter it out of the_content()

```
function nona_url_grabber() {
    if ( ! preg_match( '/<a\s[^>]*?href=[\'"](.+?)[\'"]/is', get_the_content(), $matches ) )
        return false;

    return esc_url_raw( $matches[1] );
}
```

But I feel like thats a lot of PT for something that should have some support....

Answer (score -1):

Personally I don't really use post formats, I tend to use custom post types instead, but as usual WP provides several ways to achieve the same result. Regardless, I think WP already has the information you need explained fairly well in the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats). In particular I think you'll find the information you want if you scroll down to just below the Function Reference content block, starting with Adding Theme Support.

In short, you can just modify your theme template files to check for the post format and output differently based on that value. For example, you might check `if( has_post_format('photo') )`, and only output the featured image for the post if it matches, or the entire normal loop if it doesn't. You could do a switch statement, or have a bunch of other conditionals in the template. You can even use separate template files (see [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display), eg. `taxonomy-post_format-post-format-<formatname>.php` ). I don't know that there's a standard or preferred approach, I suggest you choose whatever fits best into your workflow.

Comment: Thanks skrivener, but unfortunately you've missed the mark, specifically I'm asking about filtering the_content() once you're inside of a template to output different media and if theres a 'right' way to parse the content for different format types, I've worked extensively with post formats and Wordpress and as I mentioned above my question does not concern the template hierarchy. Lastly, custom post formats are an entirely different concern, are not an alternative to post formats, post formats are more like a preset custom taxonomy for specific media or output

Comment: I think your question is not specific enough, although I think perhaps I might see where you're heading. To clarify: I think you're asking what is the best way to parse the content of a given post in order to format the output. Can you confirm that this is what you want, and if not, perhaps an example with some code or pseudocode would help?

Comment: actually, after to re reading this question, its pretty specific and I've solved it now, will post the solution shortly.